# how to use yii active record updateall method

Tags: php, yii

How to use correctly updateall method from active record? Is it safe?
I simply use it like:

```
$rows = $this->updateAll($attributes, 'full_path = :path', array(':path' => $path));
```

But here what is written about it in documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateAll-detail:

> Updates records with the specified condition. See find() for detailed
>   explanation about $condition and $params. Note, the attributes are not
>   checked for safety and no validation is done.

Does it mean that we it's vulnerable for example to sql injections? Do we need to call validate method before using it? Is using methods of CDbCommand more safe if to use binding than using updateAll?
Thank you in advance for you answers. I hope they'll be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the method isn't vulnerable to `sql injection` **IF** you bind the params using the third paramater.

This method is calling `createUpdateCommand` from `CDbCommandBuilder` class and this method bind the value to the prepared statement so you shouldn't be vulnerable to SQL injections

> no validation is done.

It means it doesn't validate the data against the validation rules you could have created in your model. So before calling this method you should verify that all data that come from a user are as they should be (if you store an int then that the data passed is an int, the string is less than 255 caracters, ...)

It's up to you to decide if you want to call the `validate` method or just make sure datas are OK

> The attributes are not checked for safety

This apply to flaw such as XSS script, no control is made that the text you store could contain some XSS or other bad javascript.

**Update**

> Attributes array is not safe?

Attributes array is safe. When you call the `updateAll` method it will call internally the `createUpdateCommand` method from `CdbCommandBuilder`

Here's how the method handle the params:

```
foreach($data as $name=>$value)
{
    if(($column=$table->getColumn($name))!==null)
    {
        //Useless code for the example
        $fields[]=$column->rawName.'='.self::PARAM_PREFIX.$i;
        $values[self::PARAM_PREFIX.$i]=$column->typecast($value);
        $i++;
    }
}
//Some useless code for the example
$sql="UPDATE {$table->rawName} SET ".implode(', ',$fields);
$sql=$this->applyJoin($sql,$criteria->join);
$sql=$this->applyCondition($sql,$criteria->condition);
$sql=$this->applyOrder($sql,$criteria->order);
$sql=$this->applyLimit($sql,$criteria->limit,$criteria->offset);

$command=$this->_connection->createCommand($sql);
$this->bindValues($command,array_merge($values,$criteria->params));
```

As you can see a typecast is performed on each params to ensure that it's type is as it should be: `$column->typecast($value);`

And then it call the `bindValues` method for the params

Comment: When I output data I always escape them for example using CHtml::encode. I was worried more about sql injection and validation of the model.

Comment: So I think you're good!
On my point of view I alway sanitize input data before putting them on the DB, in case for example I forget to call CHtml::encode. This is also usefull if several medium can retrieve the data (eg an api)

Comment: I wonder why I can bind param for condition, but not for field values I update.

Comment: Does it mean I the code in my question is safe from sql injections? Attributes array is not safe? I use param only for condition. Does code from underlying layers deal with them?

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that we it's vulnerable for example to sql injections?

Not if you use the params instead of query string concatenation - that's what's the params are designed for. See note below.

> Do we need to call validate method before using it?

That is up to you whether you need validation for the values in your model's attributes.

An example of how you would use this without validation is when you want to toggle a boolean value programatically for several items.

> Is using more safe if to use binding?

Using params is somewhat the same as binding - it also prevents SQL injections.

---

**Note:**

The keyword 'safe' in Yii does not refer to the prevention of SQL injections, but whether the attributes will be copied to the model when you mass set/override the attributes. E.g.:

`$model->attributes = $_POST['MyModel'];`

Read more here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/

Comment: I updated my question. Do you mean it's safe from sql injection to pass array of attributes to update all (attributes array is not safe)?